# How do I step out of a loop with Ruby Pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, exit, pry

I'm using Pry with my Rails application. I set `binding.pry` inside a loop in my model to try and debug a problem. For example:

```
(1..100).each do |i|
  binding.pry
  puts i
end
```

When I type `quit`, it goes to the next iteration and stops again. Is there a way to step out of the loop so I don't have to type `quit` 100 times?

Currently the only way I know how to get out of it is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and restart the application.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

To exit Pry unconditionally, type

```
exit-program
```

**Edit from @Nick's comment**: Also works:

```
!!!
```

Comment: Though you'll obviously hit the binding straight away, using just `exit` will allow the program to keep running.

Comment: This did not work for me when running `rspec`.  But CTRL-C, twice, did.

Comment: on Mac OSX, pressing `Ctrl + C` twice will kill the Pry session, but will also effectively kill that terminal window: subsequent output is glitched such that I need to close that terminal tab and move to a new one. However `!!!` does not have this aggravating effect.

Comment: @Evandro You have no idea how this saved me!

Comment: Warning: If used inside an rspec test it can cause the test to falsely go green. Use the answer by @stebooks instead: `disable-pry`

Comment: In case somebody struck with * icon shown on pry command with Mac terminal , do single ctrl + C to start using Pry again

Answer (score 124):

I use:

```
disable-pry
```

This will keep the program running, but will keep it from continuing to stop execution. This is especially helpful when you are debugging in the console.

Comment: To re-enable (from the command line): ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil

Comment: i was not able to reenter pry after using disable-pry.  Even after using  ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil

Comment: To reenter pry, all you need to do is to set `ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil` in your controller not in command line OR rails console.

Comment: This is the perfect one to use when you're using guard and just want it to stop running pry for that test run.  It'll reset on the next test run.

Answer (score 42):

To exit everything, use:

```
exit!
```

This should ignore all proceeding bindings.

Comment: This also kills the server at the same time. `exit-program` is still probably the best option if you don't want to restart the server.

Comment: Just to clarify `exit-program` allows you to maintain your `rails server` session but seems to throw a `SystemExit`

Answer (score 25):

Triple exclamation (`!!!`) would do that.

Comment: This was the solution for me on OSX 10.11.4 (El Capitan), I did not try the `disable-pry` + `ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil` combo but I did try `exit-program` which gave me a systemExit. This one just works. (On **rails** 3.2.22.2, **pry** 0.10.3 and **ruby** 1.9.3)

Answer (score 20):

Use

```
disable-pry
```

To renable, add this to your controller

```
ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil
```

Answer (score 14):

A `binding.pry` statement is exactly the same as a breakpoint in GDB. Such a breakpoint in GDB would be hit 100 times too.

If you only want the `binding.pry` to be hit once, for the first iteration of the loop, then use a conditional on the `binding.pry` like so:

```
(1..100).each do |i|
  binding.pry if i == 1
  puts i
end
```

You then exit the current session by just typing `exit`.

Answer (score 3):

press 'q' and you will see just like this

```
[1] pry(#<AlbumsController>)>
```

type

```
exit
```

this one word will do, if not:

```
control + c
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the two previous answers above:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21735420/3137698
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24945487/3137698

Thank you guys! Your advices have helped me really a lot!

I just want to share a simple stupid trick, that I personally use to don't worry about the `DISABLE_PRY` environment variable all the time. Add this callback to the base controller `ApplicationController` of your project permanently. It would automatically re-enable PRY every time the `disable-pry` is called:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :reenable_pry

  private

  def reenable_pry
    ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using gem `pry-moves` you can step out of loop using `f` (finish command)

---

example:

```
    42: def test
    43:   3.times do |i|
 => 44:     binding.pry
    45:     puts i
    46:   end
    47:   puts :finish
    48: end

[1] pry(main)> f
0
1
2

Frame: 0/1 method
From: playground/sand.rb:47 main

    42: def test
    43:   3.times do |i|
    44:     binding.pry
    45:     puts i
    46:   end
 => 47:   puts :finish
    48: end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to debug one iteration, you can just raise error, escape guarantee :

```
(1..100).each do |i|
  binding.pry
  raise
  puts i
end
```

Or with condition :

```
(1..100).each do |i|
  if i == 50
    binding.pry 
    raise
  end
  puts i
end
```