# How do I exit binding.pry without exiting my rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

When I'm going through a loop and I've seen what I needed to see in the terminal, I don't want to keep having to `continue` to finish off the loop, I just want to exit back to my terminal. But when I type `exit!` it exits out of the server as well. If I type just `exit` without the bang, it keeps going thru the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I step out of a loop with Ruby Pry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015531/how-do-i-step-out-of-a-loop-with-ruby-pry)

Answer (score 8):

The method or command you are looking for is:

```
disable-pry
```

You can find this command by typing `help` in pry console. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

To exit without stopping the server, a triple bang will work:

```
!!!
```